# Functions satisfying $f(\lambda x)\leq\lambda f(x)$ for some $\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Fix some $\lambda>1$. I am interested in the class of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  which satisfy  $f(\lambda x)\leq\lambda f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Does this class depend on $\lambda$? Or is it the case that if $f$ has this property for one $\lambda$, then it has it for all?

I was trying to start with $\lambda=2$ and $\lambda=4$. It is straightforward to show that any $f$ with this property for $\lambda=2$ also has this property for $\lambda=4$. But I was unable to prove the converse which somehow makes me believe that the converse is just not true. But I was also unable to find a counter example.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your question: There exists a function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(2x) \le 2f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, but $f(\frac32 x_0) > \frac32 f(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is definitely related to the question. I am happy with Kavi's answer below but I would also be interested in your example if it is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=(x-2)^{2}$ for $1 \leq x \leq 3$. For any $x>0$ there exists an integer $n$ such that $3^{n} \leq x \leq 3^{n+1}$. Define $f(x)$ as $3^{n} g(3^{-n}x)$. Define $f(0)$ to be $0$ and let $f(-x)=f(x)$ for $x >0$. Then $f$ satisfies the given inequality only when $\lambda $ is of the form $3^{n}$.

[In particular, If $1<\lambda <1.5$ and $x=2$ then $f(\lambda x) >\lambda f(x)$].

Comment: How can it be valid only for a single $\lambda$? Doesn't $f(\lambda x)\leq\lambda f(x)$ imply $f(\lambda^n x)\leq\lambda^n f(x)$ for all positive integers $n$? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Hi Kavi, thanks for the answer! Just checking whether I understand it correctly: The integer $n$ depends on $x$, right? So maybe one could write $f(x)=3^{-n(x)}g(3^{n(x)}x)$ with $n(x)=\lfloor\log_3(x)\rfloor$?

Comment: Also the minus should be inside $g$ I guess

Answer (score 1):

**An example**:

Let
$$f(x) = \frac{36x^2 + 36x + 17}{36x^2 + 36x + 36}.$$
We have, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$2f(x) - f(2x) = \frac{144x^4 + 216x^3 + 119x^2 + 51x + 17}{36(x^2 + x + 1)(4x^2 + 2x + 1)} > 0.$$

Let $x_0 = - 4/5$. We have
$$f\left(\frac32 x_0\right) - \frac32f(x_0) = \frac{263}{15624} > 0.$$